# In metro, is there any way to get FolderInformation for the KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

As far as I know, `FileInformation` and `FolderInformation` are both created through `FileInformationFactory`. But `FileInformationFactory` can only return the sub-folders or sub-files in the folder, not the folder itself. So if I want to get the `FolderInformation` for the top-level folder, like `KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary`, it seems no way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually pictures library is not itself a folder in the traditional sense of a folder.  It is just a collection of locations you want to include in a logical entity called a library.  And these locations need not even be in a proper hierarchical order.  So a library probably doesn't have properties like a folder does.